# AWS Service Catalog provisioning of products with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cloudformation, cicd

I am currently trying to deploy a AWS Service Catalog product (Cloudformation template) via terraform. My deployment happens with an IAM Role assumed by another BUILDER Accounts. This deployment role has full admin rights. By manual deployment via AWS Console, the Service Catalog product can be deployed. This is my terraform module:

```
resource "aws_servicecatalog_provisioned_product" "network" {
name                     = "reporting"
product_id               = "prod-mirxxxxx"
provisioning_artifact_id = "pa-mirxxxxx"

provisioning_parameters {
  key   = "AllowFrom"
  value = "0.0.0.0/0"
}
```

Unfortunately I always get an error during the terraform deployment:

```
module.reporting.aws_servicecatalog_provisioned_product.network: Creating...
module.reporting.aws_servicecatalog_provisioned_product.network: Still 
creating... [10s elapsed]
module.reporting.aws_servicecatalog_provisioned_product.network: Still 
creating... [20s elapsed]
module.reporting.aws_servicecatalog_provisioned_product.network: Still 
creating... [30s elapsed]
module.reporting.aws_servicecatalog_provisioned_product.network: Still 
creating... [40s elapsed]
module.reporting.aws_servicecatalog_provisioned_product.network: Still 
creating... [50s elapsed]
module.reporting.aws_servicecatalog_provisioned_product.network: Still 
creating... [1m0s elapsed]
module.reporting.aws_servicecatalog_provisioned_product.network: Still 

Error: error provisioning Service Catalog Product: ResourceNotFoundException: No launch paths 
found for resource: prod-mirxxxxx
```

Has anyone an idea, unfortunately I couldn't find anything how to fix this issue.

Comment: I'm wondering if this solution here can help? https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/8404

Answer (score 0):

I used the AWS command line to give me the LaunchPaths:

```
aws servicecatalog describe-product --id prod-xxxx --region eu-west-1
{
"ProductViewSummary": {
    "Id": "prodview-xxx",
    "ProductId": "prod-xxx",
    "Name": "AWS Control Tower Account Factory",
    "Owner": "AWS Control Tower",
    "ShortDescription": "AWS Control Tower Factory product. Provisions a new AWS Control Tower managed Account.",
    "Type": "CLOUD_FORMATION_TEMPLATE",
    "HasDefaultPath": false
},
"ProvisioningArtifacts": [
    {
        "Id": "pa-xxx",
        "Name": "AWS Control Tower Account Factory",
        "Description": "AWS Control Tower Factory product. Provisions a new AWS Control Tower managed Account.",
        "CreatedTime": "2022-02-14T12:19:51+00:00",
        "Guidance": "DEFAULT"
    }
],
"Budgets": [],
"LaunchPaths": [
    {
        "Id": "lpv2-xxx",
        "Name": "AWS Control Tower Account Factory Portfolio"
    }
]
```

}